Set up triple integral
$$
\mbox{Compute}\quad
\iiint_{E}xy^{2}z\,\,{\rm d}V
$$
where $E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the region above the $xy$-plane bounded by
$$
z = \sqrt{x}\quad\mbox{and}\quad x = 4 - y^{2}
$$
My attempt: $E$ can be described ( simple along the $z$ axis) by
$$
E = \left\{\left(x,y,z\right) \mid -2 \le y \le 2,\ 0 \le x \le 4-y^2,\ 0 \le z \le \sqrt{x} \right\}.
$$
I also want to describe $E$ as simple along the $x$ axis:
$$
E = \left\{\left(x,y,z\right) \mid -2 \le y \le 2,\ 0 \le z \le \sqrt{4-y^2},\ z^2 \le x \le 4-y^2\right\} ,
$$

I feel like my first one is right.
Which one is correct ( or both are wrong ) ?.
Does "simple along the $x$ axis" mean $E$ has to be projected onto $yz\mbox{-plane}$ to find the domain for $y$ and $z$ ?.
Is there a systematical way to do this projection thing ?.

Thank you.

Not sure if it's a typo, but in the first $E$, $0\le x\le y^2$ should be $0\le x\le 4-y^2$

@Andrei It should be. I made the correction. If that's the case, is my $E$ correct? Thank you.

First one is now correct (I've changed the sign). Not sure about the second

The second setup is also correct, both integrals give the same result.

"Is there a systematical way. . .projection thing." -- I would always relabel the axis' (e.g. I might switch every appearance of z and x in a problem or something similar) so that I only ever had to consider the projection onto the xy-plane. It made it easier for me as I was more accustomed to graphing/visualizing in terms of x and y. Not necessarily "systematic" but was a trick I frequently employed.
